# External Device Media Indexing in chunks [Android Media framework]

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediascanner

Can we read data between Scan_Started to Scan_finished in chunks?

I Have pen drive with 5000 songs it will around 1-2 min to index all media file.

I want to know whether i can read the file at every 100 insertion into MediaProvider database cocurrently.

So that user don't have worry about whole scanning to be done [it can happen in background].

Answer (score 0):

We can use Content observer on Media Provider to get the notification whenever data is changes in Media Db.